# Process only mailboxes where folder permission is not equal to

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I got a script for setting all mailboxes calendar permissions in Exchange Online to PublishingEditor for -User Default, and that works as it should.

But I can't seem to get it working so it only processes the mailboxes where the permissions is not equal to PublishingEditor.

It still runs through all the mailboxes, even if they are already set.

I've tried using the following code.

```
$allmailbox = Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited

Foreach ($Mailbox in $allmailbox)
{
    $path = $Mailbox.alias + ":\" + (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $Mailbox.alias | Where-Object { $_.Foldertype -eq "Calendar" } | Select-Object -First 1).Name

    If ($path.AccessRights -ne "PublishingEditor") {
        Set-Mailboxfolderpermission -identity $path -user Default -accessrights PublishingEditor
        Write-Host 'Done'
    }
    ElseIf($path.AccessRights -eq "PublishingEditor") {
        Write-Host "ALREADY DONE"
    }    
}
```

Comment: Does $Path have a parameter 'Accessrights' ?  You have to use Get-MailboxFolderPermission in some way to get them

Answer (score 0):

Below the code I wrote to do this. It works on my system.

```
foreach ($mbx in Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited) {
  Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $mbx | Where-Object {$_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar'} | ForEach-Object {
    $path = "$($MBX.Alias):$($_.Folderpath)".Replace('/','\')
    $DefaultPermission = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $path -User Default
    if ($DefaultPermission.AccessRights -notcontains 'PublishingEditor') {
      Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $path -AccessRights PublishingEditor -User Default
    }
    else {
      Write-Host 'Already Done'
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of assigning all mailbox objects to a variable first, a foreach statement is used with the Get-Mailbox in it. Once you get to administer an Exchange system with thousands of mailboxes you will experience why it's better